# HTTP WMS request working but not using WMS client?

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm new using MapServer and I want to serve some layers using WMS.  I managed to see the layer using the browser but I've got an error using the same URL in QGIS (Error downloading http://localhost/cgi-bin...). I've also tried ArcMap and is not loading the layer either.

My URL is:

http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/paola/wmsdemo/htdocs/wms.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=hu3&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-8.9,54.12,-4.46,58.6.50&WIDTH=1177&HEIGHT=602&FORMAT=image/png&

I tested the link using this web WMS and it is also working (wmsviewer-rodis.rhcloud.com).

Do you have an idea why the URL is not working in this software?

Comment: Try to delete all between the ? and SERVICE .Those map definitions may not be working for Qgis and ArcMap.

Comment: Don't believe in the previous comment. Without some tricks on the server side you can't leave out the "map=..." parameter. What was the connection string that you used with QGIS? I hope you do not use the whole GetMap url. And what do you have as  "wms_onlineresource" metadata? See http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html for reference.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS is happy with this as the URL:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/paola/wmsdemo/htdocs/wms.map&
```

QGIS adds the request=GetCapabilities and other parameters. Once you've got that working, it will give you a dialog to select the layer and will form the bounding box and other parameters for you.